# How to make child route take full page in a nested route in angular

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have a parent route called PRODUCTS and in this route I have a child route called CREATE-PRODUCT. When user clicks on CREATE-PRODUCT button, its meant to navigate to the create-product route but I still see the parent route content shown instead of making the CREATE-PRODUCT path full and have that content alone. What am I missing? I have images explaining how I went about it. I know I'm wrong somewhere. Please help.

THE CREATE PRODUCT ROUTE SHOWS ON THE LEFT SIDE WHEN BUTTON IS CLICKED INSTEAD OF TAKING FULL PATH
[image]

MY ROUTING IMAGE
[image]

I THEN PLACED THE  IN THE PARENT (PRODUCT) COMPONENT
[image]

I INTEND TO MAKE SURE SIDEMENU SHOWS THE ACTIVE STATE. HERE IS HOW I ADDED ACTIVE STATE TO EACH ACTIVE ROUTE IN MY SIDEMENU.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `create-product` route is a child of `products` route and as there is a router-outlet inside the `ProductComponent`, this is where the `CreateProduct` component will be rendered (that's why we see it on the top of your ProductComponent on the screenshot).

Update your route architecture in order to keep the active state on products route :

```
{path: 'vendors', component: VendorsComponent, children: [
    {path: 'products', children: [
      {path: '', component: ProductsComponent},
      {path: 'create-product', component: CreateProductComponent},
    ]}
  ]}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking out time. But won't that take away the active state as shown in the products side-menu? The goal too is to retain the active state for sidemenu. Letting user know its still within products.

Comment: how do you set the active state? Please add the sidemenu template code

Comment: I just did. I use routerLinkActive for the routes. Screenshot has been added too.

Comment: I update my answer, you need to change your route architecture

Comment: Thank you!!! Works like a charm. I had the same architecture for whole layout of the admin but never thought of it this way to structure for child routing. Thank you so much.